# Python eliminar y procesar toda una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando organizar una carpeta, me interesa eliminar de una lista, que no del directorio (al menos por ahora) determinados elementos, por ejemplo los archivos ocultos.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import os

files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

print("All files:",len(files))
for f in files:
    if f.startswith("."):
        print(f)
        files.remove(f)

print("Remaining files", len(files))
for f in files:
    print(f)
```

Creo que lo que me ocurre es que la lista me va dando saltos y hay elementos que no se procesan.
Como puedo evitar eso si es que fuera el caso?
Por ahora lo que he probado también es a crear una lista con los elementos que si que quiero procesar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No debes eliminar elementos de una lista mientras iteras por ella, pues puede causar que se pierdan elementos.

Si lo único que necesitas es una lista con los elementos a procesar, puedes crearla "filtrando" (no dejando pasar) los que no quieras. Por ejemplo, usando una *comprensión de listas* como esta:

```
a_procesar = [ f for f in files if not f.startswith(".") ]
```

Si quieres, puedes asignar el resultado a la misma variable `files`, con lo que aparentemente habrás eliminado los elementos no deseados (en realidad no eliminas, sino que creas una lista nueva que ya no los tiene)